# Can a Flash SharedObejct expire per session?

Tags: flash, session, cookies, shared-objects

I'm trying to display certain content per session, but the site has the same Flash embedded in the different sections of the site, so I can't set it on the site's Model or a Global Variable. I also can't use PHP or JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sharedObject could have a "state" property to identify which section of the site the user is currently interacting with. When the user changes section, update the property. Within a specific section , query the property whenever you need to select what content to display.

Another option could be to set your sharedObject with a unique session identifier when a user enters a specific section of the site, using both localPath and a unique name then clear it when the user leaves the site's section

Have a look at this article for more info on setting a name & a localPath:
http://jaycsantos.com/flash/the-trick-to-using-sharedobject/

Comment: thanks! that guided me in the right direction!